# How to pass Nodejs Data to a PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, email

Currently, I'm building a User registration system where one of the components is to send an email confirmation to the registering user. This is easy in PHP due to its built in mail function, but not so in Nodejs. I would use the Nodemailer, except for the fact that it requires a license in commercial use, and I want to avoid paying money I can avoid.

As such I've opted to use Nodejs as a means to interact with MySql DB and PHP scripts to implement the few systems that Nodejs cannot.

My question here is: how to I pass data (in this instance say an array) from Nodejs to a PHP script that will receive this data and use it to send an email using the mail function.

Comment: You can have a webservice to which send data via POST request. Or you can save data to the DB with Node and the retrieve them from PHP once you call the script. Also... you can send the mail via Node. Or you can encode the array insto a string and run the script via PHP cli.

Comment: @Effe Right now I've achieved communication between the javascript file and PHP file, what's stopping me now is that when I post To The PHP file, I can't receive the sent data.

Comment: assuming that is the PHP file under server, check the way you send data from Node, beware at the Content-Type, if you send data in JSON format you can't find them in the $_POST array